# Cannot consume JSON data source from proxy service

Tags: javascript, html, json, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to consume the data source from a proxy service, and the data source has the following structure:

```
{
  "Items": {
    "ItemSection": [
      {
        "Food": {
          "Name": "Potato Chips",
          "itemID": "24501"
        },
        "category": "Snack",
        "description": "Some description",
        "available": "Shop A"
      },
      {
        "Food": {
          "Name": "Cookie",
          "itemID": "24510"
        },
        "category": "Snack",
        "description": "Some description in here.",
        "available": [
          "Shop A",
          "Shop B"
        ]
  },
```

Below is the response headers :

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Access-Control-Request-Method: OPTIONS, GET
Cache-Control: public, max-age=321
Content-Length: 42158
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 29 Sep 2016 20:45:49 GMT
Expires: Thu, 29 Sep 2016 20:51:11 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 29 Sep 2016 20:31:11 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Vary: *
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: Authorization, Content-Type
access-control-allow-origin
```

and this is how I consume the data source with JavaScript:

```
function getItems() {
    var uri = "proxy url goes here";  
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        showItems(resp.value);
    }
    xhr.send(null);
}

function showItems(item) {
    var tableContent = "<tr class='ItemTitle'><td>Item Lists</td></tr>\n";
    for (var i = 0; i < item.length; ++i) {
        var record = item[i];   
        tableContent += "<tr><td>" + record.Name + "</td></tr>\n";
    }
    document.getElementById("showItem").innerHTML = tableContent;
}
```

The data source doesn't show up as I run the page, all I got is a blank page with the title `Items` displayed only. But if I replace the code inside `xhr.onload = function() {}` to this:

```
var version_d = document.getElementById("ItemLists");
version_d.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
```

Then all data source will be displayed on the page but it just displaying a raw data source and I cannot select what I want to show on the page by using `showItems` function.

Here's my html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ShowOrders.css" />
        <script src="ShowOrders.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = getItems;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Items</h1>
        <table id="showItem"></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why it is not working with `JSON.parse` ? am I using the Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) method wrong ? How can I get it works with out using any external libraries or frameworks (pure JavaScript only) ?

Comment: So what is the error? Is there one in the browser's console?

Comment: Are you able to get that string from the `xhr.responseText`?

Comment: @AskingQuestions Yes I can display those raw data with `version_d.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;`

Comment: so JSON.parse() is not throwing an error? Did you look to see what is in the response? `var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); console.log(resp);`

Comment: @epascarello sorry there's actually an error: ShowOrders.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: resp has a value child right. `resp.value`

Comment: See nick's answer.

Comment: So you are saying your JSON is like this `{ "value" : [] }`, but that is not what you have.... What are you trying to look over exactly? `ItemSection` ??

Comment: `showItems(resp.Items.ItemSection);`

Comment: @epascarello Thank you, I just realize I used a wrong name...

Answer (score 0):

`resp.value`

JSON.parse directly returns.the parsed object, so `resp.value` is undefined.

You just want

`return resp;`